# Direct basis definition

Tags: differential-geometry

I came across a paper where a *direct basis* is chosen. In particular, a basis in the five-dimensional Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}_1^5$. For this space they also consider, before taking the basis, an orientation by requiring
$$dx^0\wedge dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3\wedge dx^4 > 0.$$
It may be also helpful to say that in this paper they work with *moving frames*, so I guess the orientation here plays an important role.

That's why I assume that the term **direct** for a basis means that it is a positively-oriented basis for the given orientation, but I couldn't find clarification for this anywhere. Is this so? Any source where this term is defined or used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging for a few days, I have found an explanation.

The writer of this paper is french, so I thought it could be some kind of notation used in his language. I googled the french term *base directe*, and the second result was this [link](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_orthonorm%C3%A9e#En_g.C3.A9om.C3.A9trie_dans_l.27espace) to the French wikipedia page of *orthonormal basis*. In this article one can find the statement "If the basis is direct, then 
[...]", where the term *direct* redirects to the French wikipedia page of *orientation*. So basically they call *direct basis* to those defined with the third vector as the cross product of the first with the second vector of the basis. In this way, as I was assuming in my question, one can divide the basis into *positively-oriented* or not. My question was about with a 5-dimensional space, which only means that we need to generalize this definition.